# How to check if IR receiver is dead or not ?

Tags: components, infrared, multimeter, testing

I have an IR Receiver , but I am not sure if it works or not, 
I want to make sure weather it's burnt or not,  How can I test this with Multi meter ? 
If it can not be tested with multi-meter, Is there any easy to test ?

[image]

Comment: I did a Google search on your image. Here's the top result:- https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor/testing-an-ir-sensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm the pin-out from the data sheet. Two pins will be DC power in; a voltage between +3.3v and +5v, the other ground. The third pin is output, which may be floating, or may have an internal high-value pull-up resistor to the positive DC supply pin. Incorrect application of power to Vdd and ground pins *can/will* easily destroy the device. Most receiver chips pull the output pin to ground when they see a sustained optical signal of the correct frequency. "Sustained" means more than about ten cycles.

The following circuit may produce *some* short LED light pulses when you excite the dome part of the receiver module with the optical signal from a TV-remote transmitter. Because these remote receivers are tuned to various frequencies (between 30 kHz - 60 kHz), you may get no indication on the LED if your remote transmitter is not frequency-matched to the receiver.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ7wiR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>